# SQL Statement - update row value to the maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey members of StackOverflow,

i just wan't to ask a question about SQL Statement for my privat project i'm working on since 2 weeks.
I want to update for example the value of life to the max. value of life without go over the max. value..

```
My Players Table:
ID | life | max_life

My Values: 1 | 97 | 100
```

and my SQL Statement looks like:

```
UPDATE players SET life=life+10 WHERE life < life_max
```

How do i get the difference from life (In this Case: 97) and life_max? Cause my SQL Statement wouldn't update the row cause it would go over the max. value
I hope someone understands my crazy english and can help me with a solution!
Greetings from Germany.

Comment: May be you simply need UPDATE players SET Life=Max_life

Comment: @Sergey Don't think so. Intention is probably *slowly* increasing life towards maximum (a game presumably).

Comment: @Sergey you're wrong, i want to update the value of Life only by 10 Points and the current value is 97, max. value is 100.

Comment: It's far from clear, but I'll guess that the desire is to add 10 but not go over the max.
In that case, UPDATE players SET life = CASE WHEN life+10 > life_max THEN life_max ELSE life+10 END;

Comment: Is the name of your table `Players` or `players`, and is the column named `max_life` or `life_max`? 
You're using two different case sensitivities and two different names of one single column

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE players SET life = CASE WHEN life+10 > life_max THEN life_max ELSE life+10 END;

The OP said this "works like a charm" (see comments above).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`LEAST()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_least.asp) function to specify a maximum value for your formula. For example:

```
UPDATE players
SET life = least(life_max, life + 10)
WHERE life < life_max
```

Comment: Could you explain this solution a little bit more?

Comment: follow the link with LEAST

Comment: @TomaszPolanski . . . Please explain how "didn't work" means.  The solution looks correct to me.

Comment: The Solution from the comments above "UPDATE players SET life = CASE WHEN life+10 > life_max THEN life_max ELSE life+10 END" works like a charm.

Comment: @TomaszPolanski: Good. I have posted that statement as an answer (see answers below). If you want to call it the accepted answer, then I guess we're done here.